# Cómo actualizar una tabla base de datos online sustituyendo por una en local sin afectar a los usuarios

Tags: mysql, sql

Quería saber si es posible sustituir una tabla de una base de datos que está online por una en local (que se va completando y ampliando) sin afectar a los usuarios ni un segundo.

En este caso es una tabla que contiene preguntas a modo test, pero en local se van añadiendo más y más preguntas, para luego sustituir la tabla que está online por la que está en local(la completada o ampliada). ¿Cual debería ser la manera correcta? Es una web que siempre tiene usuarios online, entonces me da miedo dejarlos aunque sea unos segundos, fuera de linea.

Gracias.

Comment: Puedes tener dos bases de datos online: la activa y la que quieres que esté online y que reemplazará la activa con los datos más actualizados. Luego cambias el load balancer para que dirija el trafico a la base de datos nueva. Creo que lo llaman blue and red o green and red o blue and green Si lo buscas en internet encontrarás más detalles, es un problema comun en entornos 24/7 que no pueden dejar de funcionar online.

Comment: Se llama blue green deployment. Espero sea de ayuda..

Comment: Mientras se hace el cambio (hacer que el load balancer apunte a la base de datos nueva) puedes haver que la base de datos antigua sea de solo-lectura hasta que se efectua el cambio.

Comment: No entiendo porqué se ha puesto en espera esta pregunta. Se plantea un problema y se indica que no se tiene clara la forma ya que la normal (borrar y volver a crear) tiene graves problemas. En fin, salvo que sea duplicada creo que es una pregunta válida y puede ayudar a mucha gente.

Answer (score 0):

La solución pasa por no borrar nada de la BD's Online sino identificar qué registros en Local no están OnLine y añadirlos.
Por lo que dices no modificas nada en Local así que es solo añadir por lo que si vinculas ambas tablas en por ejemplo MS-Access y preparas una query así debería funcionar:

```
INSERT INTO TablaRemota (campo1, campo2....)
SELECT campo1, campo2....
FROM TablaLocal
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
     FROM TablaRemota 
     WHERE TablaRemota.ID = TablaLocal.ID)
```

Obviamente no es fácil de probarlo por mi parte pero suelo hacer así este tipo de cosas y funcionan muy bien.